# Unified Call Syntax and Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, function-call, c++17

[A bit of background for the unified call proposal](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-unified-call-proposal)

Does *Unified Call Syntax* allow C++ programmers to easily cast *a member function pointer* to *a non-member function pointer* and vise versa?

In other words, does it allow to call **a member function** via *a non-member function pointer* by sending the class's instance as the first parameter?

```
struct X
{
    void member() { }
};

X x;

void (*fp)(X*) = &X::member; // ?
fp(&x);                      // ?
```

Comment: If you simply want to call it, not necessarily store it as a plain function pointer, isn't that was [std::invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is going to be for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that can't ever work, because a pointer-to-member-function can't be represented by a simple function pointer. A pointer-to-member-function must be able to handle virtual calls on the object it's applied on, and so it must contain (or trigger the generation of) code to dereference a vptr when necessary. I.e., it's not a regular pointer you can just `call` into.